# How to grant access to user group when creating a project in openshift via a yaml

Tags: openshift

I want to grant different roles (view, admin) to user groups after creating a project via a yaml.

1. Create a new project.
2. Grant user group "abc" view role
3. Grant user group "xyz" admin role.

Similar to below, but in a yaml file
oadm policy add-role-to-group view abc -n test

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Have you run 'oc adm policy add-role-to-group view abc -n test -o yaml --dry-run' to see what it creates?

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton, this was helpful.